# Looping in Python: modify one column based on values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, loops, if-statement

## Current data:

Stored as a Pandas DataFrame

```
print(df)

col1 | col2 
A    | 1
B    | 3
C    | 3
D    | 7
E    | 4
C    | 3
```

## Goal:

I want to create a new column that adds 1 to col2 if col1 is either A, C, or E.

```
col1 | col2  | col2_corrected
A    | 1     | 2
B    | 3     | 3
C    | 3     | 4
D    | 7     | 7
E    | 4     | 5
C    | 3     | 4
```

## My failed solution:

```
add_one_to_me = ['A','C','E']

if df.col1.isin(add_one_to_me):
    df.col2_corrected = df.col2 + 1
else: df.col2_corrected = df.col2
```

This throws an error about ambiguous truth because it is assessing the truth of the entire series.

How do I apply this to each row of the DataFrame? I am new to Python and programming, so it's a pretty basic question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# Copy the existing column over
df['col2_corrected'] = df.col2

# Increment the values of only those items where col1 is A C or E
df.loc[df.col1.isin(['A', 'C', 'E']), 'col2_corrected'] += 1

df
Out[]: 
  col1  col2  col2_corrected
0    A     1               2
1    B     3               3
2    C     3               4
3    D     7               7
4    E     4               5
5    C     3               4
```

The reason you get that error is from the line `if df.col1.isin(add_one_to_me):`

If we take a look at: `df.col1.isin(add_one_to_me)`

```
Out[]: 
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5     True
```

And this doesn't bode with the `if` statement. What you could have done is **iteratively** checked each item in `col1` and then increment `col2_corrected` by one. This could be done by using `df.apply(...)` or `for index, row in df.iterrows():`

Comment: For performance purposes, I would avoid `iterrows` and stick with `apply` if you go that route

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that the integer value of `True` is 1

```
df['col2_corrected'] = df['col2'] + df['col1'].isin(add_one_to_me)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the functionality of `map` alternatively i.e

```
df['new'] = df['col1'].map({'A':1,'C':1,'E':1}).fillna(0) + df['col2']

   col1  col2  new
0    A     1  2.0
1    B     3  3.0
2    C     3  4.0
3    D     7  7.0
4    E     4  5.0
5    C     3  4.0
```